# Retrieve image from Oracle DB

Tags: c#, oracle, asp.net-web-api, oracle11g, blob

So, i am using a web api to retrieve a image!! But, at the DB the image is a LongRaw. Im seeing at the google that i need to use the OracleDbType.Blob 
But, when i try to use this,

```
public IEnumerable<FotoEnvolvido> GetFoto(string suspid)
        {

            DataSet lretorno = new DataSet();

            string connectionString = GetConnectionString();
            using (OracleConnection connection = new OracleConnection())
            {
                connection.ConnectionString = connectionString;

                OracleDataReader reader = null;
                OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand();
                cmd.InitialLONGFetchSize = 50000;
                cmd.Connection = connection;
                cmd = new OracleCommand("MOBILE.XAPIMANDADOMOBILE.BUSCAFOTO", connection);
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

                //variáveis entrada            
                cmd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("SUSPID", suspid));
                //variáveis de saida          
                cmd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("oretorno", OracleDbType.Blob)).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;

                connection.Open();
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                OracleDataAdapter da = new OracleDataAdapter(cmd);

                da.Fill(lretorno); 

                reader = cmd.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection);

                //CRIO A LISTA
                lretorno.Load(reader, LoadOption.OverwriteChanges, "BUSCAFOTO");
                connection.Close();
                connection.Dispose();

                var teste = lretorno.Tables[0].AsEnumerable().Select(row => new FotoEnvolvido
                {
                    FOTO = (byte[])(row["FOTO"]),
                });

                return teste;
            }
        }
```

i have a error on cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()      :

```
"ORA-06550: linha 1, coluna 7:\nPLS-00306: número errado ou tipos de argumentos na chamada para 'BUSCAFOTO'\nORA-06550: linha 1, coluna 7:\nPL/SQL: Statement ignored"

Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleException was unhandled by user code
  DataSource=""
  ErrorCode=-2147467259
  HResult=-2147467259
  IsRecoverable=false
  Message=ORA-06550: linha 1, coluna 7:
PLS-00306: número errado ou tipos de argumentos na chamada para 'BUSCAFOTO'
ORA-06550: linha 1, coluna 7:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored
  Number=6550
  Procedure=""
  Source=Oracle Data Provider for .NET, Managed Driver
  StackTrace:
       em OracleInternal.ServiceObjects.OracleCommandImpl.VerifyExecution(OracleConnectionImpl connectionImpl, Int32& cursorId, Boolean bThrowArrayBindRelatedErrors, OracleException& exceptionForArrayBindDML, Boolean& hasMoreRowsInDB, Boolean bFirstIterationDone)
       em OracleInternal.ServiceObjects.OracleCommandImpl.VerifyExecution(OracleConnectionImpl connectionImpl, Int32& cursorId, Boolean bThrowArrayBindRelatedErrors, OracleException& exceptionForArrayBindDML, Boolean bFirstIterationDone)
       em OracleInternal.ServiceObjects.OracleCommandImpl.ExecuteNonQuery(String commandText, OracleParameterCollection paramColl, CommandType commandType, OracleConnectionImpl connectionImpl, Int32 longFetchSize, Int64 clientInitialLOBFS, OracleDependencyImpl orclDependencyImpl, Int64[]& scnFromExecution, OracleParameterCollection& bindByPositionParamColl, Boolean& bBindParamPresent, OracleException& exceptionForArrayBindDML, Boolean isFromEF)
       em Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
       em WebApiApp.Controllers.FotoController.GetFoto(String suspid) na C:\Users\50216740\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\AppMobilePCRJ\AppMobilePCRJ\WebApiApp\Controllers\FotoController.cs:linha 49
       em lambda_method(Closure , Object , Object[] )
       em System.Web.Http.Controllers.ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor.ActionExecutor.<>c__DisplayClass10.<GetExecutor>b__9(Object instance, Object[] methodParameters)
       em System.Web.Http.Controllers.ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor.ActionExecutor.Execute(Object instance, Object[] arguments)
       em System.Web.Http.Controllers.ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor.ExecuteAsync(HttpControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary`2 arguments, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
  InnerException:
```

**If i use OracleDbType.RefCursor like the others web apis that i get strings, don´t give me this error...the problem is that the parameter comes [{"ISUSPID":0,"FOTO":""}], even when on DB brings me the image!**

What i am doind wrong, thats the FOTO is empty on Json ???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what lretorno.Load(...) is doing to read the data, but this sudo code sample using a select statement might help you... I've always had to specifically get the blob and read it out to get the bytes in the past.

Example for retrieving a **LONG RAW** DataType

```
var imgCmd = new OracleCommand("SELECT photo FROM photos WHERE photo_id = 1", _con);
imgCmd.InitialLONGFetchSize = -1; // Retrieve the entire image during select instead of possible two round trips to DB
var reader = imgCmd.ExecuteReader();
if (reader.Read()) {
    // Fetch the LONG RAW
    OracleBinary imgBinary = reader.GetOracleBinary(0);
    // Get the bytes from the binary obj
    byte[] imgBytes = imgBinary.IsNull ? null : imgBinary.Value;
}
reader.Close();
```

Example for retrieving a **BLOB** DataType

```
var imgCmd = new OracleCommand("SELECT photo FROM photos WHERE photo_id = 1", _con);
var reader = imgCmd.ExecuteReader();
if (reader.Read()) {
    // Fetch the blob
    OracleBlob imgBlob = reader.GetOracleBlob(0);
    // Create byte array to read the blob into
    byte[] imgBytes = new byte[imgBlob.Length];
    // Read the blob into the byte array
    imgBlob.Read(imgBytes, 0, imgBlob.Length);
}
reader.Close();
```

Comment: Sorry for the delay !! And thanks for the answer... 
But who is the parameter "blob" ? that you used blob.Lenght

Comment: as you can see from the reader you get the oracle blob object which can tell you the length of the blob and then that object also has the read function to populate a byte array

Comment: in imgBlob.Read give me the error "cannot convert a long to int" on imgBlob.Length

Comment: i used (int)imgBlob.Lenght and ok !! But, i am having error because of OracleDbType !! If i use .RefCursor, i have error on OracleBlob imgBlob = reader.GetOracleBlob(0)...something about conversion !! If i use .Blob, i have error on ExecuteReader() ... something about "one or more arguments..."

Comment: Must you use the stored procedure? I've never worked with a blob output from a stored procedure... what is your stored procedure doing? Typically if your going to store a blob in your database you have an ID for that blob and select/update/delete directly via the ID. Any filtering/conversion is done outside of the database, you can always store additional versions of the blob in the database to cache filters/conversions, then you would use an additional column to identify that

Comment: its a get...i want to retrieve the image, that is stored as a Longraw on DB. I don´t know exactly how works the stored procedure, because they did it for me and gave the name...when i test on DB, it works.

Comment: Ok that makes sense then why it's not working if your using a LONG RAW. If your using a version of oracle database newer then 8i oracle recommends using BLOB datatype instead of LONG RAW see: http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/LONG_RAW however according to http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/win.112/e23174/featData.htm#ODPNT281 to get a LONG RAW type you can use reader.GetOracleBinary() or reader.GetBytes(). I'll update my answer with a GetOracleBinary()

Comment: Ok ! i will try it... i am out of the work on vacation...but i will come back

Comment: If you don´t mind, after get the bytearray, how i use this with Json ? I don´t know if i work with the bytearray and at the Client side, i convert to image...do i am wright ?

Comment: Yes of course you can. Ask a new question and link here I'll answer or someone else can