# How to Convert ORACLELOB object to Image File using C#?

Tags: c#, oracle, image-conversion, lob

I have an Oracle Database Table where an image is stored in LONG Data Type. I want to retrieve this as an image file(Tiff file).

According to my research, LONG data column has to be first converted to LOB object and then into image file.

By using OracleClient library and TO_LOB function I have been able to receive ORACLELOB object from the database. However, I have not been able to convert this ORACLELOB object to an image file.

Any idea on how to do this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Retrieve image from Oracle DB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39045383/retrieve-image-from-oracle-db)

Comment: @OldProgrammer This question is about LONG RAW to image. I am trying to convert LONG to Image. I believe LONG and LONG RAW are different.