# Fetching table data along with blob data using web api

Tags: c#, oracle, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2, blob

I am trying to fetching records from oracle database table using web api from country mater table having columns "CountryName", "CountryCode" and "country image" (blob). I am not able to include blob column along with other data:

**Current Code:**

```
   // Data Access (Repository) layer for fetching data using Dapper
    public override IQueryable<Country> GetCountryList()
             {
               string query = "select CountryName, CountryCode from Country";
               connection.Open();
               return connection.Query<Country>(query).AsQueryable();
             }    



   // Web API controller
    public IHttpActionResult Get()
            {
               var JsonResponse = ;
               return Ok(GetCountryList().ToList());
            }
```

**Expected Result:**

I want to include CountryImage column which is BLOB type along with existing columns (query below for reference).
i.e. *"select CountryName, CountryCode, CountryImage from Country";*

I will be consuming this data in my Angular application.

Comment: Take a look at this : [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39045383/retrieve-image-from-oracle-db](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39045383/retrieve-image-from-oracle-db)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To embed a BLOB into json, the code will have to encode to base64 so it can be included in the json

This has been covered in this SO answer:

[Base64 encoding and decoding in oracle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3804279/base64-encoding-and-decoding-in-oracle)

Comment: Thanks for sharing; also let me know in case you know of any limitation of this approach ?

Comment: Sheer size will be the limiting factor. Clearly doing xxGB this way won't be ideal.  For that I would make the JSON have a reference URI then that URI is a targeted access to the LOB which could be streamed binary.